# issue with pushViewController on main thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I would like to do the following:

```
 [self.navigationController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushViewController:animated:) withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I am not sure however on how to pass in the view controller and the bool animated value in here? Can anyone help me out? My guess is that I pass in a NSDictionary in the withObject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super methods(pushViewController:animated:) can not override, so you should be like a below code.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushMyViewController:) withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:<#yourViewController#>,@"viewController", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"animated", nil] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

---

```
- (void)pushMyViewController:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[info valueForKey:@"viewController"] animated:[[info valueForKey:@"animated"] boolValue]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make a method to do that stuff.

```
   [self.navigationController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushViewController:animated:) withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Will become:

```
[self.navigationController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(someMethod) withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:NO];

-(void)someMethod
{
    //pushViewController:animated: //and other stuffs
}
```

Comment: this method will then need the viewController and also the animated or not, how do I pass it in?

Comment: also then someMethod would have to be inside the UINavigationController class right? I'd have to implement a category to do that

Comment: That, or he needs access to the navigationController, which shouldn't be too hard to manage.
About the animated. You can control that by properties or globals just as easy as passing it through..
The someMethod can call on his own the method you wanted to implement in the performSelectorOnMainThread

Comment: Pretty much the same as the other answer ;)